# fazer redirecionamento na view

Tags: cakephp

Como posso redirecionar no cakephp com base no seguinte código:

```
<noscript>  
//redirecionamento aqui  
</noscript>
```

estou usando:

```
<noscript>  
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=error.ctp">  
</noscript>
```

está dando o erro que no controller não existe a action error.

A view não permite $this->redirect();

Como faço. Sei que não é a convensão do cake. Se alguém me orientar também neste detalhe, fico grato.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu CakePHP?

Comment: Como exatamente você gostaria de fazer? Quando o usuário entrar na página, ele já seja redirecionado para outra?

Answer (score 0):

Monte a url da seguinte maneira e substitua por:

```
$url = Router::url([
    'plugin' => 'seu plugin ou null',
    'controller' => 'seu controller',
    'action' => 'sua action',
    '_full' => true // essa é opcional, se quiser q monte a url completa, coloque como true, senão, só tirar
]);

<noscript>  
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=<?php echo $url ?>">  
</noscript>
```